# Windows clients aren't detecting new Domain Controller for logins

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I just setup a new Windows Server 2008 R2 domain controller in our environment to add additional redundancy.

DNS seems to work on the new server. However, when I shut down the previously existing DC and try to login with a client within the same subnet as the DC, it will not login.

Is there something I need to activate on the new DC to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you configure the clients to use the new DC/DNS server for DNS? Did you install the DNS role on the new DC? Does your AD DNS zone have the correct A and SRV records for the new DC?

Comment: DHCP for the subnet includes the new DC. DNS role was added as part of dcpromo and I've verified it as working. A and SRV records exist for the new DC for the site. Is there something else I need to do on the client side to make sure they know the new DC exists?

Comment: *Is there something else I need to do on the client side to make sure they know the new DC exists?* Nope, as you're not setting static IP information on each client. Are you trying to add an aditional DC to a domain or replace an old DC here? How many other DCs in the domain?

Comment: @RobM The DNS info has been added to DHCP and after manually renewing the DHCP lease, I've confirmed that the clients do indeed detect the new DC as a DNS server as they are support to. There are 3 other DCs total but only one other DC in this site. When I shutdown the other DC in the site (that works) clients are not able to login using anything besides cached credentials. Additionally, when the other DC is setup, the clients will not pickup an IP from the other DC even though I configured them with split DHCP scopes (which is likely related).

Comment: Is the new DC and the subnet it's on associated with a site in AD Sites and Services?

Comment: The clients are on a different subnet than the DCs so I believe I need to set an IP helper on the Cisco router. Will test on Monday and confirm once I've done so.

Comment: An IP Helper is a DHCP relay agent. It has nothing to do with AD or DNS. If the clients are getting valid DHCP assigned ip addresses in their respective subnets then setting up an IP Helper isn't going to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there's nothing you need to activate for it to work. Let's break down where the problems will most likely be.

### DNS

The first rule of Active Directory is that if you have a problem, *it's always DNS*. You said that the DNS role is already installed on your new DC. Good. Now you need to verify that your clients are actually using it as a secondary DNS server. Log into a client that's problematic and run `ipconfig /all` and look at the listed DNS servers. If your new DC isn't listed alongside the first one, then that's your problem. Generally, you configure the DHCP server to hand this out (Your DHCP service wasn't on the DC that you shut down, right?!).

If you *did* add this to the DHCP options for your DHCP server, then you'll need to make sure you've waited long enough for the clients to process this change. They only update their leases halfway through the lease period. If you've got the default 8-day leases, you won't see clients starting to use both DNS servers with regularity until 4 days in. You can use `ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew` to force a client to update their lease info and pull down the new DNS servers.

### DHCP

A lot of people run their DHCP servers on one of their DCs. I personally don't like doing this, but in a small environment it is fine. If your first DC is the one with the DHCP Server role and you shut it down, things won't get new addresses. Depending on how you're testing this, it could be causing your problems. No IP connectivity == no login.

### Failed Promotion

This is rare, but sometimes a DC fails during promotion. Check your event logs, specifically the Directory Services logs for anything ominous.

Comment: I believe DHCP may be where the problem resides. I've configured the new DC to also be a DHCP server with a separate scope of IPs. However, I believe this just led me to the issue. I think I need to configure an additional helper IP on my Cisco router to point to the new DC as well for DHCP.

Comment: Didn't you just say that the clients that can't log in are on the same subnet as the DCs? That means that you don't need an IP helper. Have you configured *both* DHCP servers to assign *both* DCs as DNS servers to your clients?

Comment: I misspoke (though I actually said the DCs are on the same subnet, I didn't say the clients were on the same subnet as the DCs), the DCs are on a separate subnet from the clients (I have my servers on a different subnet than clients). I believe the IP Helper may be the resolution here as I've found supporting documentation elsewhere on the internet. However, I'm not going to implement a change like that at 4:30pm on a Friday...will report back on Monday if that is the solution.

Comment: Ah well yeah. Your clients wouldn't be able to get IPs from the new server without it *but* clients with existing leases should be able to connect just fine as long as your test is `log out, log back in` and not `reboot, log in`. Good luck!

Comment: Good to know. My test actually was reboot, log in so that explains that as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the record, it was the IP Helper that needed to be configured on the Cisco router that finally got this working. However, your response was what got me thinking about that so I'm awarding the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)